# Datomic free failed on OpenJDK 17

Tags: clojure, datomic

[Datomic free](https://my.datomic.com/downloads/free/0.9.5703.21) 0.9.5703.21 was tested on clojure 1.10.3 and `openjdk 17` but failed below,

```
$ bin/maven-install

$ bin/transactor config/samples/free-transactor-template.properties
=> System started datomic:free://localhost:4334/<DB-NAME>

$ clj -Sdeps '{:deps {com.datomic/datomic-free {:mvn/version "0.9.5703.21"}}}'
user=> (require '[datomic.api :as d])
nil
user=> (d/create-database "datomic:free://localhost:4334/test")
Execution error (ActiveMQInternalErrorException) (ChannelImpl.java 404)
```

No error occurs if we just downgrade to `openjdk 8`. How to make it cope with `openjdk 17`?

Comment: You may wish to try the Clojure mailing list at clojure@googlegroups.com  or also try  https://forum.datomic.com/